# Chrome Browser won't load custom font from remote URL

Tags: css, email, fonts, font-face

Using this in my web page css to use a custom font:

```
      @font-face {
    font-family: "Bryant-Light-LIV";
    src: url("http://www.[mywebpage].com/wp-content/uploads/promos/bryant-light-webfont.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
  }
```

This works on all browsers except Chrome. However, when I use a relative URL for the custom font it works on all browsers INCLUDING Chrome.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Bryant-Light-LIV";
    src: url("img/bryant-light-webfont.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
  }
```

Unfortunately, this is going to be an HTML email, so I can't use a local file reference for the font. Any reason this might be happening or suggestion to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me, from Google fonts:

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3ZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2212, U+2215;
}

.openSans {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

Here's a codepen link https://codepen.io/palash/pen/baOxZG

Edit: Since you are sending this in an e-mail, I think there will be a limited amount of fonts that you can use, and depending on the e-mail client, your external fonts might not get loaded. You can rely only on system fonts in that case.

Comment: You haven't read the question. Does it work in an email message read from, let's say, Outlook, or Thunderbird? It might work in Gmail, although I doubt it does even there.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, also, the question clearly says 'webpage', and says that it works in all browsers except chrome. It might still work, but you can't control what it will be like inside e-mail clients like outlook, for example.

Comment: I'm curious why it would work in Chrome when loading from a local font file, but fail when trying to download the same exact font file from a remote url? Is it the unicode-range?

Comment: Is it possible it needs to come from an https url? Or would it work just because it's a white-listed google font site?

Comment: @Palash Karia, Anything beyond web safe fonts do not work in Gmail. You can use a system font to style Gmail on your computer, but unless the recipient has the same system font, it will not work in Gmail. Google Fonts do not work in Gmail.

Comment: It works without the unicode range too, you can try it out. This is just what google uses. CORS can be one problem, if you don't have it enabled on your font server. You should also see a warning in the console in that case. And ofc it wont work properly in e-mails. But in a webpage, this should just work. 

Also, if you want to design e-mails, consider using something like mailchimp or some framework like [zurb](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html), or MJML[https://mjml.io/], they make it easier.

@gwally that's right, you can only style it and hope the recipient has a similar font

Answer (score 1):

This method will reliably work for email clients for IOS and others for Google Fonts:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

Add this to your `<style>` sheets in relevant areas:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

I tried to see what Typewolf recommends for using Bryant in email, but you're on your own. Hopefully it supports a `<link>` or `@import` and allows you to link to it's font server like Google does.

**Web fonts do not work in Outlook or Gmail**

Gmail does not support web fonts of any kind, including Google Fonts. Outlook support seems to depend on the font. Any typeface with a space in the name causes Outlook to revert to it's default font, Times New Roman. Web fonts do not work with Yahoo! or Notes, among others.

This will give you a better idea what works in email:

- https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts
- http://campaignmonitor.com/css/

Good luck.